# An example web service for creating content in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I want to use already existing service of Drupal, to create a content on my drupal site from a stand alone plugin using ajax call. Can anyone provide the details...?Is there any webservice which I can use.

Comment: Wait, you want to use Drupal to create content from not Drupal? I don't understand the question but it seems to involve handing over admin access to a 3rd party webservice.

Comment: The flow would be like, I have a native desktop html+Javascript UI which will create an oAuth request for my drupal site.once the app is authenticated , it creates ajax request to a rest end point of existing web service on Drupal for various crud operations. e.g. creating a content

Comment: So basically my requirement is any existing service which I can add on my drupal site and how to install that service and the respecitive details of its usage....

Comment: What is the point of this, I still don't understand? If your point is to change the look and operations of the admin interface just build your own admin theme.

Comment: I do not want to change the look or operation of admin interface... We are working on some extension via which a user can use their drupal site for content management using the extension without spciafically logging into the site etc...Their will be many other functionalities to be added....

Comment: I have got a helpful site : https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/services/ regarding the same... I have created a simple service as well using the steps mentioned... Now I just want to know how to use this service for authentication and other functionality for my extension

Answer (score 0):

okay I feel I understand you enough to attempt an answer; unfortunately, it may not be the answer you're looking for because you seem to want to authenticate admins with oAuth instead of logging in using the standard Admin API. You will notice that almost no oAuth login modules support this type of Admin authentication (I've been using: https://www.drupal.org/project/gauth) - indeed it would be a huge modification to Drupal core API rather than an extension to it so I'd be worried about using anything that tried to.

Before we get into it, I **highly** recommend comepletely disabling User #1 and using a different user with admin access to perform your admin operations. More info on why you should do this [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/947312).

You said:

> a user can use their drupal site for content management using the extension without spcicfically logging into the site

However, anyway you look at it your user needs to be authenticated or else how can you trust they should be posting as admin? You'll notice that Drupal uses session data to keep user sessions alive. Let's take a look at an example of the cookie which gives you admin access:

```
cookie                                  value                                           domain                  path    expires                     HTTP
SESS92fe1e89dd2d30d5c7ef053b44d061s5    bJzbNlFKnbwvoTOH8A1XBWHipcRPnC32wOBdAJiEmJg     example_domain.com      /       2015-07-09T21:46:07.841Z    true
```

I created that cookie just a second ago, so as you can see, by default, a Drupal admin cookie remains valid on a user computer for a bit less than a month. There's various methods of getting this session data into your application, the simplest is just to use an `<iframe>` wrapper. Iframe logins **DO** work with Drupal and have been tested here: `http://jsfiddle.net/z1rrj4ky/`

Just make your own custom login page and module to style it like the rest of your extension. Once you have the admin cookie returned to your application, you don't even need the Drupal admin theme pages to post content. You just need access to the Drupal API functions by including them. One way of achieving this quickly is to keep an installation of Drupal locally to your application that has the target server's Database. You can setup the extension's DB to be linked with the target DB by modifying the settings file located at: `<drupal_root>/sites/default/settings.php` or, in some cases: `<drupal_root>/sites/default/default.settings.php` If you need access to more than one DB you don't need to have multiple installations of Drupal, just change the `environment var` or redefine the settings based on `var` that come from `constants`.

Once this is all setup you can serve your content posting pages anyway you want to. If you don't want to use the Drupal Admin interface using a custom theme, just create content programmatically and serve them anyway you want - even from outside of the Drupal root folder.

For example:

```
// get access to Drupal API functions from outside of Drupal
// This example assumes a sibling directory to the Drupal directories
// it can be easily modified to instantiate from directories much 
// further away or deeply nested
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
chdir($path);
define( 'DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd() );
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/common.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/module.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/unicode.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/file.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/session.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
// now you can use all drupal functions:
// For example, let's check if current user is admin:
global $user;
$user_array = (array) $user;

if ( array_key_exists ( 3, $user->roles ) ) {
    $user_type = "admin"; // admin to save the day!
} else {
    $user_type = "user"; // not an admin, can't post or edit content doh!
}
```

Once you've verified user has posting and editing privileges, and if you're against using the native admin wrapper with a custom theme, you'll find there are lots of tutorials to show you how to programmatically create or edit content; for example - https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922 shows you how to programmatically create a node.

**Recap:**

- Disable User #1 and use a different admin account
- Authenticate with an iframe, if your really against it you can authenticate using oAuth in your extension use the token success callback to post to another page which posts `environment variables` or `constants` from hashed SQL table entries to auth Drupal admin without the user seeing it. If you do this definitely **hash** the contants or environment vars or whatever.
- make sure your local extension version of Drupal is hooked up to target site's database by modifying `settings.php` in the `<drupal root>/sites/default/` folder
- Once you're authenticated and verified you're hooked up to the right DB you can handle posting or edit content either with native Drupal interface using a custom theme, or bootstrap Drupal using an adjustment of the above code to instantiate the D6 or D7 API from anywhere in your project.

GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Remember, all you really need access to is the target database. However, it's highly discouraged trying remove Drupal from the equation when posting or editing content as it will have for sure post unforseen problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks Drew! Regarding the sentence "without logging into the site" does not meant that the user does not need to be authenticated. It meant that user would be using our extension's custom login page to get authenticated by using OAuth ...1

Comment: Thanks Drew! Regarding the sentence "without logging into the site" does not meant that the user does not need to be authenticated. It meant that user would be using our extension's custom login page to get authenticated by using OAuth. So the approach would be : 1) User first authorizes the extension to post content on drupal on his/her behalf.2) The extension should get something called client id and secret from drupal.

Comment: 3) User authenticates itself via the extension either by grant_type=password or the grant_type= extension's client credentials(i.e. id and secret) The extension would send a rest api call for Oauth with the required input and would get the access token with some expiry time which would be saved locally... the extension can then use the same token for further requests for respective CRUD operations...

Comment: Also I am not using php for the request call and using javascript or jquery and ajax for the rest api requests.Also if I get any example web service already implemented for this, it would be great as I dont know php.So would be difficult create a new webservice.If i get any rest webservice module already implemented for crud operations It would be great!

Comment: I've given you clear step by step instructions on how to safely achieve what you want. Remember that Drupal is fully PHP, and if you want use Drupal CRUD you will have to interact with the PHP api. Seems you want some ready made "web service" to do everything so you don't have to write code, but I've already explained why you cannot authenticate Admin users using oAuth as this is **NOT SUPPORTED** by the Drupal API and any solution which claims to is almost certainly insecure. You're still asking the same questions. I will not be updating this thread further.

Comment: Hi Drew, I understood the above steps. and I am working on it. For the time being I just wanted to know about already existing web service module to have reuse of the code and avoid repeat..anyways thanks for all your help... I am working on the adviced steps as well...